# What does this if assignment/statement mean in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

Our professor gave us this code. It assigns a value to a char[] depending on the value of the first index in the array. He said it was an if statement but I've never seen one like this. I'm new to c++

```
temp.byte[0] = byte[0] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
```

Comment: if byte[0] == '0' then temp.byte[0] is put equal to '1' else '0'

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a ternary operator, and they're kinda weird. They're a shorthand for an if-statement.

The format is:

```
condition ? if-true : if-false
```

In this case, the condition is `is byte[0] == '0'`. If true, `temp.byte[0]` is set to `'1'`, otherwise `temp.byte[0]` is set to `'0'`.

Answer (score 4):

[Ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) are common to a lot of languages. It's roughly equivalent to an `if` that returns either the first or second value. The first value is used in the *true* case, the second if *false*. A way to remember this is `condition?` is a sort of question and the first thing after that is the answer.

There's a few guidelines for using them:

- Don't use a ternary when an equivalent `if` would be simpler.
- Don't nest them.
- Don't use a ternary unless you're assigning the result to something.
- Try to avoid using them in function arguments.
- Don't use negative conditions, instead flip the order of the last two parts.

Comment: Not so sure I agree with your guidelines.  The first is a tautology: "Don't  use X when Y is simpler" is true for all X and Y (including the case where X is an `if` statement and Y is a ternary operator).  Nesting them is a common idiom; they chain just like `if`, and are no more difficult to read than nested `if`.  As for the third: probably the most frequent use of ?: in my code is in return statements.  As for the fourth: one frequent use is as an argument to a `<<` (or to `printf` in C).

Comment: I might add  that another frequent use of the ternary operator is as an initializer.  Which can't be done with an `if`.

Comment: I'm just providing some caveats here so that discovering ternaries does not lead to someone applying them in every circumstance they can think of.

Comment: Then I'd say that the most important thing is to format them like an `if`, with the condition and each result on a different line.  (Of course, this may be overkill for very simple ternary expressions, particularly when they are used as an argument.)  If you do this, and understand the `if`-like nesting, even things like `return cond1 ? value1 : cond2 ? value2 :...` are easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is equivalent to:

```
if byte[0] == '0'
  temp.byte[0] = '1'
else
  temp.byte[0] = '0';
```

This is a basic stuff in c++. Take a look for example at www.learncpp.com

Comment: It's not quite the equivalent, except maybe to the compiler.  If the key element in the code is setting `temp.byte[0]`, then the ternary operator is significantly more readable than the `if`.  And it avoids repetition of the expression on the left hand side of the equals.

Comment: And of course, `int i = cond ? value1 : value2;` is _not_ the same as `if ( cond ) int value1; else int value2;`.  (Replace `int` by a type which doesn't have a default constructor, and you'll really see how important the ternary operator is.)

Comment: @James Kanze My answer claims that the example given by OP is equivalent to the code that I wrote. OP's example uses a trivial type, but not a class with lack of default constructors. My answer doesn't imply  that there is equivalence for a general case. Regarding your first comment - indeed using the ternary operator is rather more concise, but being significantly more readable does not annul the equivalence. But it is good to note your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
temp.byte[0] = byte[0] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
```

can also be interpreted as

```
temp.byte[0] = (byte[0] == '0' ? '1' : '0'); //L-value is `temp.byte[0]`
```

In other words,

"Does `byte[0] == '0'`?

If it does, then `temp.byte[0] = '1'`

Else, `temp.byte[0] = '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fully parenthesized expression makes the meaning of the ternary operator more clear:

```
temp.byte[0] = ((byte[0] == '0') ? '1' : '0');
```

Comment: If OP doesn't know what ?: means, how does adding () help?

Comment: Good point. I saw that the other posts already explained the meaning of the ternary operator quite well. I'm thinking that part of the OP's confusion stemmed from an inability to parse the expression, so I was suggesting a more readable way of writing it.